# onClick listener is not working for custom drawer layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, navigation-drawer

My NavigationView XML is :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_img"
         >
        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_navigation" /> </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and my java code is:

```
TextView tv_inicio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.home_inicio);
             tv_inicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    System.out.println("Home Incio Clicked .");
                }
            });
```

OnClick Listener not working.. Only this appeared in debug mode 
"D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN"
My Header Layout is which i am including in navigation View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src = "@drawable/menu_logo_03" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home_inicio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/inicio"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/enventos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/eventos"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dm_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dm"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/barrios"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/barrios"
                 />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gremios"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gremios"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/proyectos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/proyectos"
                 />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/daniel_medios"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/danielme"
                 />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/conoce"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/conoce"
               />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/radio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/radio"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code is Running and I am able to get ids of these textviews. but onClick Listener not working..

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: in which layout  home_inicio is defined?

Comment: @NehaK in nav_header_navigation

Answer (score 0):

You should add the header in `app:headerLayout` like this, not as a separate include layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
```

Comment: The layout has images, so it will not work. i had done this before. but no gain

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intention well, you may want to print a text whenever the button clicked. If that was what you meant, try to display your text in Logcat screen not in commands prompt, like this:

```
Log.d("significant index", "your text");
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println("Home Incio Clicked .");
```

Comment: I have set the debugger. Debugger is not hitting in onClick Listner method.:)